# How to compare two multidimentional array and return parent key in php

Tags: php

for example i have two arrays

```
$first = array(52=>array(10,24),55=>array(5,25))
$two = array(52=>array(10,24),55=>array(10,25))
```

in above two arrays how to return parent key if arrays values are not match , expected out put is

```
array(0=>55)
```

Comment: I would start by writing a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `array_udiff`:

```php
$first = array(52=>array(10,24),55=>array(5,25));
$two = array(52=>array(10,24),55=>array(10,25));

function compare_func($a, $b)
{
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
}
$diff = array_udiff($first, $two, 'compare_func');

print_r(array_keys($diff));
```

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 55
)
```